# Google Maps API how to hide UI within iframe

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I got my API key, and constructed my embed code like so:

```
<iframe
    id="map-canvas"
    width="450"
    height="250"
    frameborder="0" style="border:0"
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=MYKEY&center=LAT,LNG&zoom=12&maptype=roadmap" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

So far so good.
Now, I'm trying to hide the default UI of the maps. I'm given this code by Google's docs:

```
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
    disableDefaultUI: true
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

What's confusing me is that this code is trying to create the map again, but mine already shows up with the `<iframe>` markup above. I've tried adding `map-canvas` id to my iframe but it the script doesn't affect it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create the map by adding empty div in your html:

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

then you can initialize it via JS:

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
    disableDefaultUI: true
  };

  // Create new map object (gets element by id #map-canvas)
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

There is no need to add the iframe when initializing the map via JS.

If you wish to completely disable the Google Maps UI check this out: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-disableUI

jsbin - http://jsbin.com/kudixegayo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Is there an error in the console? Can you please make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you please change the script in the HTML to: ```<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>``` where API_KEY is the key you got from google and see if it works?

Comment: I did. It said API key is not valid or jsfiddle iisn't allowed to access the map. But it should be able to.

Comment: It's a jsfiddle thing - works find in jsbin: http://jsbin.com/kudixegayo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing the Google Maps JavaScript API with the Google Maps Embed API. If you want to have control over the appearance of the map you must use the JS API; follow this [simple example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple).